# (newbie) Homebrew install failing

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I'm new to all the dev world and I'm facing problems to install Homebrew in a recently formatted Mac.
macOS Catalina 10.15.4
Xcode cli installed and updated
when running the code from brew.sh (/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)")

I'm getting the following error:

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
HEAD is now at 3247f26a3 Merge pull request #7479 from sjackman/requirements. 
==> Tapping homebrew/core.
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 116, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (116/116), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (82/82), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
**fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

fatal: early EOF. 
fatal: index-pack failed 
Error: Failure while executing**; `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core` exited with 128.
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core` exited with 1.
Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force 
==> Installation successful!

**When I run brew doctor this is the result:**

~ % brew doctor
==> Tapping homebrew/core
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 116, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (116/116), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (82/82), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining. 
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core` exited with 128.
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core` exited with 1.

After all that I can't install cask and I'm getting the same error.
Any help would be much appreciated, remembering I'm new to dev world.